# XML Shape Drawable not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-drawable

I am trying to achieve the following effect which is a circle that appears to be floating: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwY20.jpg

To achieve this, I'm using two `ImageView`s populated with a shape drawable each. The circle `ImageView` is laid on top of the shadow `ImageView` to give the appearance that the circle is floating. My layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shadow_ImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shadow"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color_ImageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that although both xml shape drawables show up in the layout preview, only the circle shows up on an actual device. Here is the definition for circle_shadow which doesn't show up on the device:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">

    <size
        android:width="48dp"
        android:height="48dp"/>

    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/clear"
        android:startColor="@color/black"
        android:type="radial"
        android:gradientRadius="125%"/>

</shape>
```

and the definition for circle which does show up on the device:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/orange"/>
    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.. change this code in your `circle_shadow`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#11000000" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="@android:color/black"
        android:startColor="@android:color/black" />

</shape>
```

Comment: `circle_shadow` now shows up but it's not a gradient obviously. I'd like to make something that looks like a shadow and not a gray circle.

Comment: That isn't going to work. In order for it to look like a shadow, the Gradient needs to be of type radial, and needs a gradientRadius.

Comment: the solid color is what fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Try out this,

shadow.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><layer-list>
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="80dp" android:bottomRightRadius="80dp" android:topLeftRadius="80dp" android:topRightRadius="80dp" />

                    <gradient android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent" android:endColor="#1A000000" android:startColor="#1A000000" />

                    <size android:height="150dp" android:width="150dp" />

<!--                     <solid android:color="#1A000000" /> -->
                </shape></item>
            <item android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">


                    <solid android:color="#F87217" />

                    <size android:height="150dp" android:width="150dp" />

                    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="80dp" android:bottomRightRadius="80dp" android:topLeftRadius="80dp" android:topRightRadius="80dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape></item>
        </layer-list></item>

</selector>
```

button.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />
```

Comment: If both layers are in one drawable, would I still be able to animate the shadow layer?

Comment: I'd like to animate the shadow outwards so that it looks like the circle is rising up.

Comment: For animation on button click you will have to create a separate selector and set the two drawables in that selector acordingly

Comment: I'm just going to be using a drawable because it makes the shadow look more realistic.